# How does solidification occur?

Tags: phase

What does it mean that "When vapor pressure of solid is greater than liquid, there is a net conversion from solid to liquid".
What exactly occurs in the process of solidification of liquids?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the amount of vapor in equilibrium with a particular condensed phase as being indicative of the relative stability of the condensed phase. A more stable condensed phase results in a lower vapor pressure.

More formally, stability of a pure substance in a particular phase is usually described in terms of its chemical potential $\mu$ in that phase. A lower (more negative) chemical potential implies a higher stability. Equilibrium between two phases means that the chemical potential in both is the same. In addition, the chemical potential of a vapor (assumed to behave like an ideal gas) can be related to the value at some reference pressure $p^\circ$ using the following equation:  $$\mu(g) = \mu^\circ + RT\log \left( \frac{p}{p^\circ} \right)$$ This means that at equilibrium with a condensed phase $$\mu(\text{cond}) = \mu^\circ + RT\log \left( \frac{p}{p^\circ} \right)$$ and that the relative chemical potential of condensed phases i and j can be related via their respective vapor pressures as $$\mu_i-\mu_j = RT\log \left( \frac{p_i}{p_j} \right)$$ This means that if the vapor pressure of phase $i$ is higher than that of $j$, the chemical potential of phase $i$ is greater than that of $j$ at that temperature and pressure of the system. And only the most stable condensed phase survives.